# Verifying Tx to cold wallet

Tags: cold-storage, viewkey

Having some trouble.  I have made a few transactions to hot wallets just fine. Balances reflect transactions.

Also sent tx to cold storage wallet addresses.

Using https://xmrchain.net/ I can see from the Tx hash that the Tx are on the blockchain so I am feeling pretty confident.

I am trying to use http://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html  to see if tx are associated with the private viewkey of the intended addresses but I get back "Failed to get transaction data! Perhaps MoneroBlocks is down?" message.  Moneroblocks is up and verifies Tx hash...

All with test amounts of Monero so no panics other than my own FOMO wanting to buy more and salt them away into cold storage.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can verify the payment with the GUI on Advanced->Verify payment

Comment: I am still CLI.

Comment: You can also use https://xmrchain.net
Search for your tx hash and scroll down to prove payment.

Comment: OK. This worked.  Awesome.  Thank you! Not sure how to give you valuable reputation points here, but if I do figure it out, I will.

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1 - from the sending wallet

You can check it from the sending wallet using monero-wallet-cli:

- find the transaction key using the transaction id (requires your wallet-cli to have `store-tx-info` set to 1):

  ```
    get_tx_key TX_ID
  ```
- check that the transaction has been confirmed:

  ```
    check_tx_key TX_ID TX_KEY RECIPIENT_ADDRESS
  ```

The output should be something like:

> RECIPIENT_ADDRESS received [AMOUNT] in txid <TX_ID>
> This transaction has 1191 confirmations

#### Option 2 - using a view only wallet

Create a view only wallet:

```
monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-view-key wallet-name
```

Then input the public address and private view key.

You will then see a list of incoming transactions for that wallet.

Comment: This - view only wallet - worked also!  Thank you.  Not sure what I just did though.  Seemed to create a wallet with same address.  Is that correct?  If so, is it just the same but just not capable to spend?  Upvotes to all but since apparently I am not reputable enough, they do not display.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly http://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html does not support RingCT transactions. So you will not be able to use this tool to verify or prove your transactions. However, you can use https://xmrchain.net/ to verify and prove txs. To to this, you will need to find your transaction using tx hash, and then you will find input text fields to decode outputs  and/or prove sending xmr. This will also decode the amounts, if they belong to you.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. Feeling v good about my cold wallets now.