# Buy with Address instead of integrated address - monero wallet GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, integrated-address, address

I ve used my address instead of an integrated address to buy monero coins via an online plateform and now the balance of my wallet is not updating. Does anyone know what I should do in this case?

When verifying with `xmrchain.net`, I get this:

[image]

the balance of my GUI is still set to zero, while via the CLI I get a balance that corresponds to the Monero I bought

[image]

How can I get the balance to sync on my GUI, I really have to update my node because it is time consuming?

Comment: Use of an integrated address is not related to your balance updating. Have you synchronized your wallet? If not here are your options: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain

Comment: Yep, I connected the wallet to node.moneroworld.com and still nothing while I know the transaction passed since I have the transactionId

Comment: Please try to verify your transaction details with xmrchain.net using your txid, view key and address: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/748/11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot proves that the transaction was sent. By using your view key and address in the decode outputs section of that page you can also see the amounts (currently hidden thanks to RingCT).

The fact that you are attempting to connect to a remote node (based on your comments about connecting to the moneroworld node) seems to indicate that you have not synced your own node yet. If your node is stuck, please [try this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/my-blockchain-is-stuck-how-do-i-unstuck-it)

Alternatively you CAN connect to a remote node (until you have the time to sync your own node). Follow the [instructions on this page](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain) again. A list of available nodes is available [here](https://moneroworld.com/#nodes)